# Chart.js not initializing the datasets

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, chart.js

I'm working on a webApp using react and Flask. I have a dataset that's need to be render in to the chart using chart.js when the page load. I declare a variable to it. And when I checked it with `console.log(initialChartData)` I see a label and data with Array(100). But when I use that variable with `useState()` and `console.log(chartData)`it out it have that label but the data is now Array(0)
This is my code

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Retrieve data from local storage and parse it back to an array of objects
    const dataFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('predictionData');
    const actulaDataFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('actualData');
    if (dataFromLocalStorage) {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(dataFromLocalStorage);
      setReceivedData(parsedData);
    }
    if (actulaDataFromLocalStorage) {
      const parsedActualData = JSON.parse(actulaDataFromLocalStorage);
      setAcutalReceivedData(parsedActualData);
    }
  }, []);


const initialDates = receivedData.map((item) => item.DayKey);
const initialPredictions = receivedData.map((item) => item.PredictionSalesQty);
const initialActualDates = actualRecievedData.map((item) => item.DayKey);
const initialActual = actualRecievedData.map((item) => item.ActualSalesQty);
const initialChartData = {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Predictions',
        data: initialDates.map((date, index) => ({ x: date, y: initialPredictions[index] })),
        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
      },
      {
        label: 'Actual',
        data: initialActualDates.map((date, index) => ({ x: date, y: initialActual[index] })),
        borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      },
    ],
  };
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState(initialChartData);
```

Why is that? how to fix it?
Thanks in advance